# Slot Filling -- Only prompting page parameter fulfillment when parameter is empty

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am using Dialogflow CX and asking a user for the following information:

1. name
2. email
3. phone

I have an intent designed that understands and saves those parameters in any permutation.  The page is design with three required parameters for each of these fields. This all works perfectly. However, the page fulfillment begins with:

"Please provide your name, email, and phone number"
"Please provide your name"

The "Please provide your name" is the Initial Prompt Fulfillment from the required parameter. How do I have that line only appear as a follow up, if the user did not provide their name?

I've tested event handlers, changing the parameters, and a few other options. I'm assuming this is a basic configuration issue but can't figure out the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add a specific prompt for your parameter `name` and make it **required** so that if it isn't provided, the agent will send the prompt to ask the user to send the input for that parameter as shown below.

**My configuration on my `check_name` parameter in which my entity used is `sys.person`:**
[image]

**My full sample conversation output:**
[image]

You may use this [Dialogflow CX Quicksart](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/build-agent) reference to have an idea on how adding a prompt in required parameters works.